# How to refresh and share access token from main isolate and background isolate

Tags: flutter, refresh-token, dart-isolates

My flutter app is using refresh and access tokens to validate requests to a c# web API. This works perfectly. However, as soon as I introduced android_alarm_manager to do some background syncing of data (using isolates), I found that my refresh tokens were becoming invalid after a while (I store my refresh tokens in local storage).

This is due to multiple isolates requesting a new access token simultaneously (as I cannot lock the method due to isolates not sharing memory). Now I am not sure what the best approach would be to keep the tokens in sync.

I was thinking that each isolate could have its own refresh and access token but that doesn't seem like a good idea as I would have to store the username and password locally. Another idea I had was to setup some syncing strategy between the isolates using isolate communication or local storage, but feels like overkill.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should find a way to only refresh the token from one isolate only, and then share the result. This way avoiding "old" invalid tokens

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Flutter Geofencing sample:

Repo: https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing/tree/master/lib/src
Article: https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

It uses SendPorts to communicate across isolates which sounds like what you need:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/IsolateNameServer-class.html

You could then update the token in any isolate and send it via a SendPort to all isolates to keep it in sync.

Comment: Thanks @athor. But sharing the token is not a problem. Its that the different isolates can refresh at the same time (a request on the front end and in the background service at the same time). This will then cause one or the other to receive an "old" invalid token.
Where one of them will be the latest and valid, but the other will continue (thinking its refreshed) with its request. Then 401 unauthorized, while all it needs is to lock and wait for the other isolate to share the correct token. Its a frustrating situation.